# Многопоточность с помощью внутреннего класса

Tags: java, многопоточность

Добрый день!
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в следующем вопросе. Корректно ли будет  организовать могопототочность с помощью внутреннего класса (см. код)? Здесь интересует как будет создаваться новый экземпляр внутреннего класа в новом потоке и как он будет свзяан с внешним классом?

```
class MainClass {

   void go() {
     for (int i=1;i<100;i++) {
        InnerClass inner = new InnerClass();
        new Thread(inner).start();
     }
   }

   class InnerClass implements Runnable {
      public void run() {
        //do something
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Код корректен, связан в указанном коде ни как. Только если не начнете использовать переменные внешнего класса. Что конкретнее имеется ввиду под фразой связан?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Экземпляр класса `InnerClass` будет создаваться в момент вызова `new InnerClass()` и будет создаваться в том потоке, в каком произошел этот вызов.
- С внешним классом он будет связан так же, как любой другой внутренний класс
- Если у Вас во внутреннем классе есть только один метод `run`, то можно обойтись анонимным классом

  ```
  new Thread(new Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      //do something
    }
  }).start();
  ```
- Или вообще лямбдой

  ```
  new Thread(() -> {
    //do something
  }).start();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Это будет работать, ничего сказать плохого не могу по поводу этого подхода

Касаемо второго. Доступ из других потоков к полям данного класса осуществляться будет, но не забудьте синхронизировать доступ к ним, иначе рискнете получить `race condition`.